# Multivariable Calculus: Finding the Tangent Plane using the Normal Vector

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The equation of plane is given by:

$c_1(x-x_0)+c_2(y-y_0)+c_3(z-z_0)=0$

---

At $(x,y_0,z)$, the equation of a plane can be used to find the tangent line in respect to $x$ and to find $dz/dx$ as:

$z = z_0 - \frac{c_1}{c_3}(x-x_0)$, where $\frac{dz}{dx} = - \frac{c_1}{c_3}$

At $(x_0,y,z)$, the equation of a plane can be used to find the tangent line in respect to $y$ and to find $dz/dy$ as:

$z = z_0 - \frac{c_2}{c_3}(y-y_0)$, where $\frac{dz}{dy} = - \frac{c_2}{c_3}$

---

The equation of the tangent plane is given by:

$z = z_0 + \frac{dz}{dx}(x-x_0) + \frac{dz}{dy}(y-y_0)$

---

My question is: can you instead solve for the normal vector **c** by taking the cross product of the vectors obtained from the tangent lines?

I learned previously that given two parameterized lines, $v_1t+b_1$ and $v_2t+b_2$, a plane can be created in the form of $(v_1 × v_2)⋅(r - r_0) = 0$.